# Jupyter notebook is taking more time in starting few things in Windows compared to Ubuntu

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I recently started using Windows, and installed Jupyter notebook.

When I call

"!pip install pandas" or anything else. The cell takes 10 seconds before actually start executing and printing lines. And also, when I call another python file function in jupyter notebook, it takes more time in Windows compared to ubuntu.

This code

```
max_pool = 16
with Pool(max_pool) as p:
    df = list(
        tqdm(
            p.imap(functionABC,
                   datas),
            total=len(datas)
        )
    )
```

Comment: the notebook is connecting.

Comment: While it won't help with speed, you should be using `%pip install pandas` these days, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern `%pip install` and `%conda install` magic commands.